# How to configure web server caddy to a return 404 error?

Tags: webserver, caddy

I use Caddy v2 in docker with Caddyfile. I need to make a location like that:

```
location /id*/ {
  return 404;
}
```

but i can't find this case in caddy documentation.
Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

```
handle /id*/ {
  respond 404
}
```

See docs for `handle`: https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/handle
and for `respond`: https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/respond for more details.

Please keep in mind that no wildcard matching is done by default so `/id*/` will match `/id/`, `/id1/`, `/iddqd/` but will not match `/id/123`. If you need to match the latter use